# Ajax.Begin form and reloading PartialView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

I have a situation where I use Ajax.BeginForm() to post some data (a comment form) to a controller method. This controller method then writes some information to the database (as long as the ModelState is valid) using the Entity Framework.

As part of my form, I use the OnSucess overload, to execute a javascript function after the form is posted. This function, basically calls another controller method (which returns a partial view - in this case the list of comments).

My problem is, that the newly added comment, isn't included in the view returned from the controller action, although I know it exists within the database.

This leads me to 2 possible options:

1. The OnSucess() function of the form htmlhelper is being executed before the controller method has actually returned.
2. Entity Framework is chaching data.

In the case of 2, I am not aware of entity framework ever caching data unless being explicitly told to do so. So I assumed it was 1.

So further to my investigation, I modified my OnSucess method and my controller action.

My form definition is as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "something" })){

...

}
```

And my controller action is defined as (details omitted for clarity):

```
public ActionResult CreateComment(CreateCommentViewModel comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var context = new myDataContext();
                var newComment = new BlogComment
                                     {
                                         BlogID = comment.BlogID,
                                         CommentContent = comment.CommentContent,
                                         CommentDateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                         CommentDeleted = false,
                                         CommentLive = true,
                                         CommenterEmail = comment.CommenterEmail,
                                         CommenterName = comment.CommenterName
                                     };
                var errorList = new List<string>();
                context.BlogComments.Add(newComment);
                try
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    errorList.AddRange(from validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors from validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors select string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
finally {
return Json(new { result = -2, message = "Error saving to database" }); // Not currently handled client side
}
                return Json(new { result = 0, message = "Sucess" });

            }else
            {
                var errorList = (from modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values from error in modelState.Errors select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
                string message = errorList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, errorMessage) => current + (errorMessage + ","));
                return Json(new { result = -1, message = message });
            }
        }
```

On finally the client side method is defined as:

```
function something(data) {
        switch (data.result) {
            case 0:
                // Sucess
                // Get the Alert 

                var message = "<strong>Thank You</strong> Your comment has been posted.";
                var myAlert = jQuery("#donemessage");
                myAlert.html(message);
                reloadBlogComments();
                break;
            case -1:
                var errorMessages = data.message.split(',');
                var html = "<strong>The following errors were detected:</strong><br/>";
                var length = errorMessages.length, element = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    element = errorMessages[i];
                    // Do something with element i.
                    html += element + "<br/>";
                }
                var myErrorAlert = jQuery("#failmessage");
                myErrorAlert.html(html);
                myErrorAlert.show(500).css("visibility", "visible");
                break;
            default:
                alert(data.message);
                break;
        }
}
```

On a return value of 0, the function reloadBlogComments() is called.

However the above modifications, prove that my first assumption (1) mentioned above is actually wrong. The success function cannot be executing before the controller has returned a value. So I am totally at a loss as to why the newly added comment is not returned with the rest of the comments.

My reloadBlogComments() function is defined as thus:

```
function reloadBlogComments() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                // edit to add steve's suggestion.
                //url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
                url: '@Url.Action("RenderBlogComments", "Home")',
                data: { 'BlogID': '@Model.BlogID' },
                success: function (newdata) {
                    jQuery("#upComments").empty().html(newdata);
                },
                statusCode: {
                    404: function (content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },
                    505: function (content) { alert('internal server error'); }
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    // handle status === "timeout"
                    // handle other errors
                }
            });
            var myAlert = jQuery("#donemessage");
            var myErrorAlert = jQuery("#failmessage");
            myErrorAlert.hide(500).css("visibility", "hidden");
            myAlert.show(500).css("visibility", "visible");

            // Clear the form
            jQuery('#CommenterName').val('');
            jQuery('#CommenterEmail').val('');
            jQuery('#CommentContent').val('');
            window.location.hash = '#comments';
        }
```

Even delaying the call to reloadBlogComments() using  `setTimeout(function () { reloadBlogComments(); }, 3000);` does not achieve a consistant value.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was simple:

```
$.ajax({
 cache:false,
 ...
});
```